# Bash script - Calling back variables

Tags: arrays, bash, if-statement

I’m trying to learn a few things about scripting and Linux systems, so I started learning `bash` scripting.

For an exercise, I’m trying to program a script that would install all programs that user chooses.

I worked out a skeleton of installation part, but I’m stuck at determining users answer.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a instal_list=("Gimp" "VLC" "Gedit")

for ((i=0; i<3; i++))
do

echo "Do you want to install ${instal_list[i]} ?"
echo
read answer_${instal_list[i]}

if [[ $answer_${instal_list[i]} == "yes" ]] || [[ $answer_${instal_list[i]} == "Yes" ]] || [[ $answer_${instal_list[i]} == "YES" ]];
then

 instal+=" ${install_list[i]}"

fi

done
```

My problem is in my `if` statement. Inside of it, I’m trying to evaluate if users answer is yes. Problem is in `answer_${instal_list[i]}` variable.

I don't know how to explain what I mean, so I will try to explain it on example.

Example :

- We run the script, and the script asks us if we want install Gimp.
- We say yes, and the script stores that answer in variable "answer_${instal_list[1]}" ("answer_Gimp").
- My problem is when I try to call back that variable ("answer_Gimp"). 
  = To call it I use "$answer_${instal_list[1]}" line, but the shell doesn’t recognize that command as answer_Gimp.

So how can I call back variable `answer_${instal_list[1]}` so that shell would recognize it as "answer_Gimp"?

Comment: If you're using bash 4.x, it has associative arrays. That would be better than indirect variables like this.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly do you mean ?

Comment: An associative array is an array that uses strings as indexes, instead of just numbers. So you can have `${answer[${instal_list[$i]}]}`.

Comment: I think that I understand now. So I would have to declare two arrays at the beginning  ( `declare -a instal_list` and `declare -A answer_` ) ?

Comment: So my `IF` should look like this : `if [[ ${answer_[${instal_list[i]}]} == "yes" ]] || [[ ${answer_[${instal_list[i]}]} == "Yes" ]] || [[ ${answer_[${instal_list[i]}]} == "YES" ]];`

Answer (score 1):

```
thing="Gimp"
answer_Gimp="Yes"

variableName="answer_$thing"
echo "The value of $variableName is ${!variableName}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have bash version 4, you can use an associative array:

```
declare -a instal_list=("Gimp" "VLC" "Gedit")
declare -a to_install
declare -A answers

for prog in "${instal_list[@]}"; do
    read -p "Do you want to install $prog? [y/n] " answer["$prog"]
    if [[ "${answer["$prog"],,}" == y* ]]; then
        to_install+=( "$prog" )
    fi
done

echo you want to install:
printf "   %s\n" "${to_install[@]}"
```

Looking at that, I don't see why you need to keep the answers in an array. But if you do, that's how you'd do it.